# perl script for removing the characters and lines below it

Tags: perl

```
PIN W[2]
DIRECTION INPUT ;
USE SIGNAL ;
PORT
LAYER M5
        RECT 0.115 0.59 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.06 0.98 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.335 1.16 0.395 1.44 ;
        RECT 0.51 0.57 0.63 0.65 ;
LAYER M3
        RECT 0.115 0.59 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.06 0.98 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.335 1.16 0.395 1.44 ;
        RECT 0.51 0.57 0.63 0.65 ;
LAYER M1
        RECT 0.115 0.59 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.06 0.98 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.335 1.16 0.395 1.44 ;
        RECT 0.51 0.57 0.63 0.65 ;
LAYER M6
        RECT 0.115 0.59 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.06 0.98 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.335 1.16 0.395 1.44 ;
        RECT 0.51 0.57 0.63 0.65 ;
END
END W[2]
```

What I wanted is to search for the number starting with LAYER M (having greatest number in the above) and print only the lines starting with RECT below it. Please refer the below snippet for how the required lines should look like.

```
PIN W[2]
DIRECTION INPUT ;
USE SIGNAL ;
PORT
LAYER M6
        RECT 0.115 0.59 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.06 0.98 0.175 1.22 ;
        RECT 0.335 1.16 0.395 1.44 ;
        RECT 0.51 0.57 0.63 0.65 ;
END
END W[2]
```

Comment: Please also show the code you've got so far.

Comment: If you interchanged the words `M6` and `M1` in the input file, should the output be still the same? That is: should the output still be the `LAYER M6` block?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I would assume so - "the greatest number" should mean that if LAYER M7 were added, that should be displayed.

Comment: @bytepusher : you are exactly correct, if we have M7 or M8 or any greater number in the flow, the greatest number and RECT lines below that  should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to not step through the file twice,
and line numbers tend to confuse me, so I've decided to post my take on it.

Good luck and feel free to comment any improvements to edit in!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die "Cannot open file < '$input_fn': $!";

my %layers;

my $layer_number;

my ( $begin_block, $end_block );

while ( my $line = <$fh> ){

    if ( $line =~ /^[\s\t]*LAYER\s+M([0-9]+)/ ){
        $layer_number = $1;
    }

    # layer number not set: Add to begin block
    unless ( $layer_number ){
        $begin_block .= $line;
        next;
    }

    # END: no further layers. Just slurp it and done.
    if ( $line =~ /END/ ){
        my $slurped_end = do{ local $/; <$fh>; };
        $end_block = $line . $slurped_end;
        last;
    }

    # store line for this block
    $layers{ $layer_number } .= $line;
}

close $fh;

# find highest block, reassemble and print
my $highest_block_number = ( sort{ $a <=> $b } keys %layers )[-1];

print $begin_block . $layers{ $highest_block_number } . $end_block;
```

Comment: Thank you @bytepusher. your script really works and i have and other issue that is will i be able to perform the same if i have multiple PIN.  for example in the above i have just one that is PIN W[2]. what is o have PIN W[3] , PIN A[2] ..etc and same LAYERS are present below the PIN.

Comment: you're welcome. Thanks for accepting. It sounds like you have a very similar problem. So that is the perfect opportunity to learn, by adapting the method I've used here or Hakon has used below to your other needs. Feel free to post another question if you're stuck, but please do really post some code then. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. It scans the lines of the file `file.txt` twice. The first time it records the maximum layer number, and the second time it prints lines if it is not a layer, or if it is the maximum layer block:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'file.txt';
my @lines;
my $max_layer_num = 0;
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    push @lines, $_;
    if ( /^LAYER\s+M(\d+)/ ) {
        $max_layer_num = $1 if $1 > $max_layer_num;
    }
}
close $fh;
my $i = 0;
while ( $i <= $#lines ) {
    $_ = $lines[$i];
    if( /^LAYER\s+M(\d+)/ ) {
        if ( $1 != $max_layer_num ) {
            while (1) {
                $i++;
                last if $i > $#lines;
                $_ = $lines[$i];
                last if $_ !~ /^\s+RECT/;
            }
            next;
        }
    }
    print; $i++
}
```

Comment: Thats got to be "$i++;" (second from last line)

Comment: @MichaelG. Are you referring to the missing semicolon?

Comment: the semicolon is unnecessary. I would still put it in. Just like I'd prefer using variable names instead of assigning to $_. The supposed efficiency gain of not doing so is annihilated by the lack of maintainability IMO. But that's just my two cents ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: thank you @Håkon Hægland this code worked for me. I will try to edit this code for multiple PIN.